# Subprocess jobs that consume a variable number of CPUs on Celery workers

Tags: celery

We have an application in which we dispose of various processing nodes for running user defined jobs (subprocesses in python *parlance*). These nodes can have either 1 or many cores (say 2 for the sake of this discussion). The users define how many cores they want to use (1 or 2) for running their subprocess. A scheduling application schedules the jobs on the relevant nodes. For example, in case we have two nodes with 1 core (A and B) and one node with 2 cores (C):

- If four jobs for 1 core are scheduled, the scheduler executes one job for 1 core in A, one in B and two jobs for 1 core in C
- If three jobs for 1 core and one job for 2 cores are scheduled, the scheduler executes one job for 1 core in A, one in B, the job for 2 cores in C and one job for 1 core waits

So, jobs for 2 cores have priority over two jobs for 1 core. This way, if the node is unoccupied, it can still be used for 1-core jobs. If a job for 2-cores pops-up, then the scheduler has to make sure not to schedule any more 1-core jobs into the 2-core node, so as to disoccupy the node as soon as possible.

This would be relatively straightforward to implement using dedicated queues in Celery: jobs that require 2 cores, go do the "2cores" queue (we'd have a single worker per processing node in this case), other jobs go to the queue of workers running on a single core.

This strategy, unfortunately, would limit the efficient use of our processing farm, as there are many more user jobs using a single core. It would be a waste to leave the 2-core queues mostly idle. We're looking for a way to auto-balance this by making maximal use of the farm, while still making it possible to run jobs which require more resources.

How can I setup a celery-based application taking those requirements into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

A worker can listen to two queues at the same time, but it picks them on round robin principle. It will first try to pick task on the first queue and if there are no tasks there it will wait until one appears. After that it will start listening on the second queue and wait until there is a task there. And so on. You may end up having too many workers waiting on tasks for the "two cores" queue and doing nothing.

Celery does not support task priority and since you can not have two separate queues at the same time I can think of only one option. You can still have two separate queues for the two kinds of tasks, but you also need a logic that periodically check the size of the queue with "two core" tasks and dynamically add or remove workers listening on that queue depending on its size.

Comment: In your opinion, could it work like this: 1. Workers consume from both queues; 2. Workers are started with concurrency set to the number of cores; 3. If a task pops-up requesting more cores, then, remove the worker from the queues with less cores until the task is done. This will guarantee the priority;  4. Eventually, the task will be assigned to the worker that is now free to consume those many cores; When the task is gone, then reset the relevant workers to consume from queues with less cores, until a new task with more cores appear (then repeat from 3)?